# What are the Best practices for handling paged data on FHIR servers?

Tags: xml, pagination, apigee, hapi-fhir

I am creating a proxy to access data on FHIR server. With the search operation on Patient resource i am getting following response from FHIR server:

```
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
       <id value="c940f66a-0eda-4f54-bedf-20e50b4e6003"/>
       <meta>
          <lastUpdated value="2015-08-07T05:47:54.761-04:00"/>
       </meta>
       <type value="searchset"/>
       <base value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2"/>
       <total value="540"/>
       <link>
          <relation value="self"/>
          <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2/Patient?_format=xml"/>
       </link>
       <link>
          <relation value="next"/>
          <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=9112cfe0-6761-44ca-b80e-701eadbb0cb5&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true"/>
       </link>
       <entry>
          <resource>
             <Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
             <...>
          </resources>
    </entry>    
       ...
    </Bundle>
```

Now when i am trying to access the url value inside `<link>` tag for which `<relation value="next"/>` i.e when i am trying to access `http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=9112cfe0-6761-44ca-b80e-701eadbb0cb5&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true`  i am not getting next page values. I am getting same data even if i changed the values of parameters _count and _getpagesoffset. 
I have tried to access these urls through proxy also but found no change in output. I am unable to get if it's proxy related issue or FHIR server issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandings the above scenario does not work for DSTU1 FHIR server, but the same works fine for DSTU2 server. So, there seems some problem with FHIR server DSTU1. No proxy issues.